# derived table doesn't exist in FROM clause of the outer query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, language-lawyer

I was reading a T-SQL book which says

> ... derived tables are defined in the FROM clause of the outer query
>   and not prior to the outer query. As far as the FROM clause of the
>   outer query is concerned, the derived table doesn’t exist yet;
>   therefore, if you need to refer to multiple instances of the derived
>   table, you can’t.

which means we can do this as a cross join:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT empid FROM Sales.Orders
) AS D, D
```

the query above produces invalid object D error.

It sounds fair enough, but if derived table doesn’t exist yet, how come below query is valid:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT empid FROM Sales.Orders
) AS D
WHERE D.empid = 12
```

I mean if D doesn't exist yet, how can we access the column by `D.empid`?

Comment: I actually don't see a connection between your documentation quote and the queries you showed us.  In the second query, SQL Server will first evaluate the subquery, and assign it an alias `D`.  After that point, `D` is defined and has a scope, and there is nothing wrong with referring to it in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'm not sure of the point you are trying to make. D exists because you have defined it "AS D". You are selecting from D. Just think of a derived table as a table you are creating within the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if D  is defined and has a scope after the FROM clause, why we can't use D again for the cross join?

Comment: @wavery    why we can't use D again for the cross join?

Comment: That's a good question +1.  The answer is probably that the makers of SQL Server (and maybe the ANSI standard) defined the behavior to be this way.  Using CTEs, however, you can get close to the cross join behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Is your issue with the T-SQL book or with how SQL actually works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which SQL is evaluated is*:

1. FROM (tables, derived tables and joined tables)
2. WHERE
3. SELECT

So `D` is not available inside the `FROM` clause but it *is* available in the `WHERE` clause.

---

* Only the operations used in your question are shown. The complete list is [available here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

Comment: I kind of get your idea, but SQL is so weird to me, for a function  in object oriented language:  ```int a = 10;  int b = a;``` is total valid, we wouldn't say because the function hasn't finished yet, so b can not access a?

Comment: The scoping rules are written in the SQL specs but I must admit I am unable to understand them.